# cloudbees jbehave plugin

Tags: jenkins, hudson, cloudbees, jbehave, jbehave-plugin

I've just migrated my CI server from an In company server to a CloudBees server.

My application uses JBehave for functional testing and on the In Company server, i had JBehave hudson plugin (http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/hudson-plugin.html) configured. In this setup my tests was always failling sillently, so after the build process, The plugin would parse the jbehave results files and mark which tests had failled, with detailled information.

Now, on cloudbees it seems that I can't install this plugin. So, what should I do? Stop failling sillently? If I do so, the feedback from tests is very Coarse grained, and they would not be helpful for developers to discover exactly which step had failled.

Is there a way to use JBehave Hudson Plugin inside cloudbees Environment?

Thanks in Advance, and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this jenkins/hudson plugin installed on DEV@Cloud as long as you have a for-pay subscription. In such case, log in to GrandCentral and use the support link to request plugin installation on your instance.

FREE accounts are restricted to the "[essential list](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/EssentialsPlugins)"

**Update :**

CloudBees announced that all subscriptions now will have all (compatible) community plugins available.